# gwt datagrid datastore , datagrid not viewed

Tags: gwt, datagrid, gwt-rpc, datastore

I try to display data in a `DataGrid`, but it does not work.

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
public DataGridAffiche2() {        
    super(true);

    AbsolutePanel absolutePanel = new AbsolutePanel();
    setWidget(absolutePanel);
    absolutePanel.setSize("1002px", "404px");
    Label lblJaiAjoutAu = new Label("j'ai ajoutÃ© au dessous de cette ligne");
    absolutePanel.add(lblJaiAjoutAu, 10, 20);
    System.out.println("ttt");
    final DataGrid<Employe> grid=new DataGrid<Employe>();
    System.out.println("ttt1");
    final List<Employe> values=new ArrayList<Employe>();

    System.out.println("ttt2");

    Employe p=new Employe();
    System.out.println("ttt3");    

    rpc.afficheEmploye(new AsyncCallback<List<Employe>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Employe> result) {
            System.out.println("ttt4");
            List<Employe> values=new ArrayList<Employe>();
            System.out.println("ttt5");
            System.out.println("datagridaffich2 avant values");
            System.out.print(values);
            System.out.println("ttt6");

            for(Employe p:result ){
                System.out.println("ttt7");
                values.add(p);
                System.out.println("values hadek est "+p);
                System.out.println("firstName du client est ");
                System.out.println("firstName du client est "+values);
                System.out.println("hada howa p "+result);
            }                  
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            System.out.println("ttt8");
        }
    });

    System.out.println("ttt9");
    grid.setAutoHeaderRefreshDisabled(true);
    grid.setAutoFooterRefreshDisabled(true);
    ListHandler<Employe> sortHandler = new ListHandler<Employe>(values);
    grid.addColumnSortHandler(sortHandler);
    grid.setRowData(values);
    grid.setVisible(true);
    grid.setSize("839px", "323px");

    grid.setEmptyTableWidget(new Label("Message afficher test"));
    System.out.println("ttt10");
    Column<Employe, String> nameColumn = new Column<Employe, String>(new EditTextCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Employe object) {
            return object.getFirstname();
        }
    };

    abstract class PendingChange<T> {
        private final Employe Employe;
        private final T value;

        public PendingChange(Employe Employe, T value) {
            this.Employe = Employe;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public void commit() {
            doCommit(Employe, value);
        }

        protected abstract void doCommit(Employe Employe, T value);
    }


    final String[] FirstNameData = new String[] {
        "Hollie", "Emerson", "Healy", "Brigitte", "Elba", "Claudio",
        "Dena", "Christina", "Gail", "Orville", "Rae", "Mildred",
        "Candice", "Louise", "Emilio", "Geneva", "Heriberto", "Bulrush", 
        "Abigail", "Chad", "Terry", "Bell"
    };

    class BirthdayChange extends PendingChange<Date> {
        public BirthdayChange(Employe Employe, Date value) {
            super(Employe, value);
        }

        protected void doCommit(Employe Employe, Date value) {
            Employe e=new Employe();
            e.setDate_nais(value);
        }
    }

    Column<Employe, Date> datepeckercolumn1 = new Column<Employe, Date>(new DatePickerCell()) {
        @Override
        public Date getValue(Employe object) {
            return object.getDate_nais();
        }
    };

    datepeckercolumn1.setSortable(true);
    grid.addColumn(datepeckercolumn1, "datepeckerDJ");

    List<Employe> items = grid.getVisibleItems();
    if (items.size() != 0) {
        int totalAge = 0;
        for (Employe item : items) {
            totalAge ++;
        }
        countnom="nombre d'Employe : " + totalAge;
    }
    grid.addColumn(nameColumn,"Nom",countnom);

    Column<Employe, String> prenomColumn = new Column<Employe, String>(new EditTextCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Employe object) {
            return object.getLastname();
        }
    };

    prenomColumn.setSortable(true);
    sortHandler.setComparator(prenomColumn, new Comparator<Employe>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Employe o1, Employe o2) {
            return o1.getLastname().compareTo(o2.getLastname());
        }
    });

    grid.addColumn(prenomColumn,"Prenom");
    Column<Employe, String> adresseColumn = new Column<Employe, String>(new EditTextCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Employe object) {
            return object.getEmailaddress();
        }
    };        

    grid.addColumn(adresseColumn,"Adresse");

    absolutePanel.add(grid, 10, 50);

    Column<Employe, Date> datepeckercolumn = new Column<Employe, Date>(new DatePickerCell()) {
        @Override
        public Date getValue(Employe object) {
            return (Date) null;
        }
    };

    datepeckercolumn.setSortable(true);
    grid.addColumn(datepeckercolumn, "datepeckerDJ");

    Column<Employe, String> btn = new Column<Employe, String>(new ButtonCell()) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Employe object) {
            return (String) null;
        }
    };


    grid.addColumn(btn, "Buttun");

    ListBox lb = new ListBox();
    lb.addItem("foo");
    lb.addItem("bar");
    lb.addItem("baz");
    lb.addItem("toto");
    lb.addItem("tintin");


    lb.setVisibleItemCount(5);
    Column<Employe, String> Combobox = new Column<Employe, String >(new SelectionCell(new ArrayList<String>())) {
        @Override
        public String getValue(Employe object) {
            return (String) null;
        }
    };

    grid.addColumn(Combobox, "ComboBox");

    Button btnQuiter = new Button("Quiter");
    btnQuiter.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            DataGridAffiche2.this.hide();
        }
    });

    CellBrowser cellBrowser = new CellBrowser(
        new TreeViewModel() {
            final AbstractDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
            final AbstractSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = new NoSelectionModel<String>();
            @Override
            public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
                return new DefaultNodeInfo<String>(dataProvider, new TextCell(), selectionModel, null);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
                return true;
            }
        }, null);
    absolutePanel.add(cellBrowser);
    absolutePanel.add(btnQuiter, 919, 316);

    Button btnAfficheDatagrid = new Button("Affiche datagrid");
    btnAfficheDatagrid.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        }
    });
    absolutePanel.add(btnAfficheDatagrid, 863, 267);
}

public List<Employe> afficheEmploye() {
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    List<Employe> lp = new ArrayList<Employe>();

    Query q = new Query("Employe");

    List<Entity> results = datastore.prepare(q).asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withDefaults());
    for(Entity employe :results ){
        Employe p = new Employe();
        datastore.put(employe);
        PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);

        for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
            String firstName = (String) result.getProperty("firstName");
            String lastName = (String) result.getProperty("lastName");
            System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + ",  inches tall  jdid");
        }
        lp.add(p);
    }
    return lp;
}
```

Comment: Be more specific. Getting some errors ?

Answer (score 0):

In success method of your rpc call you are creating new local list and adding data to that local list named values which is never passed to your data grid.

There are two solutions to this

1) either use

```
 dataGrid.setRowData(values); 
 dataGrid.redraw();
```

in success method.

2) or use ListDataProvider.